# Why are my columns getting set very wide when I call setColumns on SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

When I create a SlickGrid this way:

```
var grid = new Slick.Grid(
  element, //needs to be something jQuery can act on: element, css selector, etc.
  dataView,
  [], //columns
  gridOptions
);
```

And then set the columns like so:

```
grid.setColumns(parameters.columns);
grid.autosizeColumns();
```

Do my columns come out very wide?

Answer (score 0):

If I remove or comment out the line:

```
grid.autosizeColumns();
```

The columns are rendered as I would expect.